# Angular /JavaScript - Odd Date Behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I realize dates can be very tricky in JavaScript, however I am encountering a somewhat strange issue.

Hopefully someone will be able to shed some light on it!

I am taking a date input from webshim datepicker and doing the following

```
                var date = $scope.date;

                console.log('date', date);

                date.setTime(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);

                console.log('after set time', date);
```

Which will log something along the lines of

```
date "2025-06-19T00:00:00.000Z"

after set time "2025-06-19T12:00:00.000Z"
```

Notice the hours are different but it's still the same day (the 19th)

However, if I switch to another view and return to this input and log the input again (different date then the one above) I get something like

```
date "2025-10-22T12:00:00.000Z"

after set time "2025-10-23T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Again the hours have changed as expected but this time the day is one day off (the 23rd vs the 22nd)

If I change view once more and return again, the logged output will return to being the same day.

Basically this behavior is being switched every time I switch views. Is this very unusual or a typical problem? By views I am referring to Angular partials e.g.

```
<script>

View 1

</script>

<script>

View 2

</script>
```

Any thoughts or advice would be really great.

Comment: you are basically always adding 12 hours to your date, you should add the 12 hours the first time only

Comment: But will it not be a different date each time?

Comment: with date.setDate you are modifying the datepicker input value, so every time that code runs you are adding 12 hours to datepicker input. Create a new date with same value as input and add 12 hours to that

Comment: Could you give an example? Have tried what you suggested but does not seem to be working, although I may just be doing it incorrectly.

Comment: var date = $scope.date;
var dateCopy = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
console.log(dateCopy)

Comment: Thank you. It seems like this should fix the issue but does not seem to be working.

Comment: Well, if you can make a minimal example in a fiddle let me know and I can check

Comment: "*I realize dates can be very tricky in JavaScript*. Dates are actually very simple objects, however people have trouble working with them. ;-)